# Photoshop CS4 Actions problem

Tags: macos, pdf, photoshop-cs4

I have quite a few images with different titles in PDF format and want to turn them into jpgs. I record the action but when applying it, all the files will have the same title as the one when I recorded the action. I'm sure there must be some preference setting. I can perform this action perfectly in CS. Please help

Answer (score 0):

On a mac you might want to just use automator for this:

[image: Automator Screenshot]